# python social auth twitter 403 followed by 220

Tags: android, twitter, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I am trying to authorize from Android using Python social, I am passing my token in format:
"xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Set the backend="twitter" and "grant_type":"convert_token"

The same thing I do for Facebook and works.

I got proper settings

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = os.environ.get('SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY', '')
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = os.environ.get('SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET', '')
```

but whenever it hits the Twitter backend class at method: user_data i.e calling the Twitters API verify_credentials.json endpoint.

it crashes with 400 response followed by:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Backend responded with HTTP403: {\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Your credentials do not allow access to this resource\",\"code\":220}]}."
}
```

I tried manually to recreate things, but the same thing happens.

I am aware of the 31 October Twitter API changes, and I added the callback urls in the Twitter's developers panel, both for the app and live/developement servers.

```
twittersdk://
http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/complete/twitter/
```

I changed the permissions to read + write just in case, but no use

```
Access permission
Read, write, and direct messages
Additional permissions
Request email address
```

Also, I refreshed the key and secret twice already and carefully placed them on backend and Android.

Before 2018.10.31 the same setup was working, but out of the sudden nothing works.

From Android I call:

```
TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession
                ().getAuthToken().token;
```

to retrieve the token.

The token is retrieved by Android using https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json

**Updates**

I tested manually with a help of twurl (ruby app)

```
twurl authorize -u 'myuser@gmail.com' -p 'mypassword' -c 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -s 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -a
```

then in ~/.twurlrc there is an access_token (exactly like Android is is passing).

However, the GET request verify_credentials.json needs token_secret as well as I debugged, property which I don't pass on the convert_token from Android

Image showing success:

[image: Insomnia test reqyest]

Question:
Do I need to extend the Twitter backend and pass token_secret param and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/issues/15
Here says that I need to pass oauth_token_secret

```
 curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=<client_id>&backend=twitter&token=oauth_token=<token>%26oauth_token_secret=<secret_token>" http://localhost:8000/auth/api/convert-token
```

Sending this as application/x-www-form-urlencoded in the request works as needed for the Android app.

Comment: Where to find the oauth_token_secret token?